# How to return all records in AspNetUserClaims

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

In ASP.NET Core / Razor Pages using Identity and Entity Framework, I can view all records in the AspNetUsers table as follows:

```
public class ViewAspNetDataModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;

    public ViewAspNetDataModel(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }

    public IQueryable<ApplicationUser> SiteUsers { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        SiteUsers = userManager.Users; // Can now use @foreach (var user in Model.SiteUsers) {} in the cshtml page.
    }
}
```

I also need to be able to view all records in the AspNetUserClaims table, but can't work out how to do this. I can include

```
IUserClaimStore<ApplicationUser> userClaims
```

in the constructor, but not sure how to resolve this in Startup.cs, and also userClaims doesn't then have a property with all claims in the database table. What's the best way to obtain this data? Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 1):

I can now answer my own question, in case this is useful to anyone else: ApplicationDbContext has a UserClaims property that has all the claims in the AspNetUserClaims table. Populate a model property as follows:

```
public class ViewAspNetDataModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext context;

    public ViewAspNetDataModel(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<IdentityUserClaim<int>> UserClaims { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        UserClaims = context.UserClaims;
    }
}
```

Then in the cshtml file you can use something like:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr style="font-size:small; color:yellow; background-color:#A00000">
            <th class="align-middle p-1" style="font-weight:normal">ID</th>
            <th class="align-middle p-1" style="font-weight:normal">User ID</th>
            <th class="align-middle p-1" style="font-weight:normal">Claim type</th>
            <th class="align-middle p-1" style="font-weight:normal">Claim value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var claim in Model.UserClaims)
        {
            <tr style="font-size:small">
                <td class="align-top p-1">@claim.Id</td>
                <td class="align-top p-1">@claim.UserId</td>
                <td class="align-top p-1">@claim.ClaimType</td>
                <td class="align-top p-1">@claim.ClaimValue</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```